# Unable to take the session variables if there is a POST method request

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Hi I am working on a simple flask rest api. I am running the front-end and backend in separate servers. The following code works if I access the server code from postman.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, session, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)

@app.route('/api/login', methods=['POST'])
def first():
    session['this_one'] = 'first'
    return jsonify({'message': 'hello', 'success':1})


@app.route('/api/messages', methods=['POST'])
def second():
    print session['this_one']

    # args = request.json
    return jsonify({'message':'fdsafd'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here I am not able to print the method in the 'second' method. The error I am getting is 'KeyError'

```
KeyError: 'this_one'
```

But if I remove the POST method it is working fine. And I double checked without the session variables and the code worked just fine. Can any one help me with this. We are also using the headers in the response. But I am not pasting that code here.

Thanks a lot.

I am posting the html code I have used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {


    $( "#login" ).click(function() {
        console.log("1")
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login",
                 data: JSON.stringify ({user: 'bbb'}),
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 dataType:"json",
                 crossDomain:true,

                 success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                     console.log("success "+data['message']);
                 },

                 error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                     // error handler
                     console.log(jqXHR);
                     console.log('fail' + status.code);
                 }
          });
    });

    $( "#go" ).click(function() {
        console.log("2")
        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/messages",
                 data: JSON.stringify ({user: 'aaa'}),
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 dataType:"json",
                 crossDomain:true,

                 success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                     console.log("success "+data['message']);
                 },

                 error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                     // error handler
                     console.log(jqXHR);
                     console.log('fail' + status.code);
                 }
          });
    });

});


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="login">aaa</button>
    <button id="go">bbb</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the log I am getting. The jquery is sending a OPTIONS request.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 16:09:45] "OPTIONS /api/login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
first
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 16:09:45] "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 16:09:52] "OPTIONS /api/messages HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 16:09:52] "POST /api/messages HTTP/1.1" 500 - KeyError
```

But if I try it with the Postman, I am not seeing the OPTIONS request. I believe I should handle the OPTIONS request in the python code. But the documentation says, flask handles it.

I am not sure what to do now. Can some one help me.

Comment: it should work, I have tested it, `127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 13:38:53] "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 200 -`
`first`
`127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 13:39:01] "POST /api/messages HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Answer (score 1):

it should work, I have verified your code:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 13:38:53] "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
first
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 13:39:01] "POST /api/messages HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I think you `POST /api/messages HTTP/1.1` at the first time, then it will raise the error, as there is no initialization for the `session['this_one']`. You should `"POST /api/login HTTP/1.1"` first to set the `session['this_one'] = 'first'`, then you can use it in the session.

**Update:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, session, request
from flask import render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') #your html goes here

@app.route('/api/login', methods=['POST'])
def first():
    session['this_one'] = 'first'
    return jsonify({'message': 'hello', 'success':1})


@app.route('/api/messages', methods=['POST'])
def second():
    print(session['this_one'])

    # args = request.json
    return jsonify({'message':'fdsafd'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

then run the flask app, you should keep html run as flask app, then it will be a web app, then from here, you can see the session is working, otherwise there is no session.

Comment: No. I am calling this from the java script and it did not work at all. And I am calling the first method first and later other methods later. Are you using the curl?

Comment: then the problem is the session issue.

Comment: maybe check your two methods are using different sessions.

Comment: Yeah it is working in the POSTMAN. Let me check with the JS file.

Comment: It fails from the jscript.

Comment: can share your jsscript?

Comment: Well... it is working for me, I have tested with your html, I put `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` to the html, I click `aaa` first, it shows `1` and `success hero` in the console, and then click `bbb`, it shows `2` and `success fdsafd` in the console, and the terminal shows all are success: `127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 16:29:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 16:29:12] "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
first
127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2017 16:29:24] "POST /api/messages HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: I don't understand. It is not working. Nothing extra in here

Comment: what do you mean by "put http://127.0.0.1:5000/ to the html"? I gave everything in the html. you need not change anything.

Comment: I didn't change anything, I just use your html as the index of the flask, when `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`, it goes to your html as index, then from here, you click `aaa` then `bbb`

Comment: I think it is the difference in the way we are running. I am running the python file with regular python command "python file.py". I am just opening the HTML file and trying to access it. Can you correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That is cool. But the thing is I am running them saparately. I am using angular2 for the front-end and the back-end is a rest-api which serves that is all. Can you try that and see if you don't mind. I will update my question.